# Unable to print once to get all the data altogether

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've written a script in python to scrape the tablular content from a webpage. In the first column of the main table there are the names. Some names have links to lead another page, some are just the names without any link. My intention is to parse the rows when a name has no link to another page. However, when the name has link to another page then the script will first parse the concerning rows from the main table and then follow that link to parse associated information of that name from the table located at the bottom under the title `Companies`. Finally, write them in a csv file.

***[site link](https://suite.endole.co.uk/insight/company/ajax_people.php?ajax_url=ajax_people&page=1&company_number=03512889)***

I've tried so far:

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://suite.endole.co.uk/insight/company/ajax_people.php?ajax_url=ajax_people&page=1&company_number=03512889"
base = "https://suite.endole.co.uk"

res = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
for item in soup.select("table tr")[1:]:
    if not item.select_one("td a[href]"):
        first_table = [i.text for i in item.select("td")]

        print(first_table)

    else:
        first_table = [i.text for i in item.select("td")]

        print(first_table)

        url = urljoin(base,item.select_one("td a[href]").get("href"))
        resp = requests.get(url)
        soup_ano = BeautifulSoup(resp.text,"lxml")
        for elems in soup_ano.select(".content:contains(Companies) table tr")[1:]:
            associated_info = [elem.text for elem in elems.select("td")]

            print(associated_info)
```

> My above script can do almost everything but I can't create any logic to print once rather than printing thrice to get all the data atltogether so that I can write them in a csv file.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking: it's not enough to just say "parse the row" as that can mean quite a number of things. What end format are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Which portion is unclear @Josie Thompson? I've already created and pasted here the script which produces the desired results. What I can't do is print once other than printing thrice to get the same results as it is producing now.

Comment: You should at least include an example of the resulting format you want, rather than just the code which might produce it. I'm also unsure of what you mean by "printing once" and "printing thrice." What specifically are you printing once and three times?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. You're not asking about how to format it correctly. However, it's still unclear what you're trying to print once instead of three times.

Comment: Check out [this image](https://filebin.net/qmuvpk5l7u311kdc) for the clarity. The blank rows represent the information of the last used name.

Comment: Are you trying to ask how you can *call* print once rather than three times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all your **scraped** data into a list, here I've called the list `associated_info` then all the data is in one place & you can iterate over the list to print it out to a CSV if you like...

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://suite.endole.co.uk/insight/company/ajax_people.php?ajax_url=ajax_people&page=1&company_number=03512889"
base = "https://suite.endole.co.uk"

res = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
associated_info = []

for item in soup.select("table tr")[1:]:
    
    if not item.select_one("td a[href]"):
        associated_info.append([i.text for i in item.select("td")])

    else:
        associated_info.append([i.text for i in item.select("td")])

        url = urljoin(base,item.select_one("td a[href]").get("href"))
        resp = requests.get(url)
        soup_ano = BeautifulSoup(resp.text,"lxml")
        
        for elems in soup_ano.select(".content:contains(Companies) table tr")[1:]:
            associated_info.append([elem.text for elem in elems.select("td")])

print(associated_info)
```